# Отсутствует элемент в Swagger - UI

Tags: java, spring, аннотации, swagger

Использую Swagger + Spring Boot + multipart/mixed. Пишу контроллер, который принимает в себя 3 файла и объект(в Swagger заносится json'ом), код выглядит следующим образом:

```html
@PostMapping(value = "/add-with-files", consumes = {"multipart/mixed"}, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ApiOperation("Описание метода")
@ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "body", value = "Объект в виде json", required = true),
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "jasperReportTemplateFile", value = "файл1", dataType = "file", paramType = "form", required = true),
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "dataTransformationScriptFile", value = "файл2", dataType = "file", paramType = "form", required = false),
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "reportGenerationSettingsFile", value = "файл3", dataType = "file", paramType = "form", required = false)
    })
public @ResponseBody CommonTemplateModel add(
    @RequestPart("json") DataModel body,
    @RequestPart("file1")
    MultipartFile file1,
    @RequestPart("file2")
    MultipartFile file2,
    @RequestPart("file3")
    MultipartFile file3
) throws CommonReportTemplateException, IOException {
    return service.add(body.toCommonTemplateModel(), 
        file1.getBytes(),
        file2.getBytes(),
        file3.getBytes());
}
```

В Swager возникает такая ситуация: [image: GUI в Swagger'e]
Как видите отсутствует Самый первый элемент, который должен загружаться в виде JSON. Буду благодарен за решение проблемы.

Comment: вы используете springfox или springdoc?

Comment: @VladimirShefer springfox